# ISet<T> serialization to JSON using DataContractJsonSerializer

Tags: .net, json

I am doing some tests to check/understand JSON serialization to/from .Net types in C#.
I am trying to use the DataContractJsonSerializer.

Here is a sample type that I am trying to serialize:

```
[DataContract]
[KnownType(typeof(HashSet<int>))]
public class TestModel
{
    [DataMember]
    public string StreetName { get; private set; }
    [DataMember]
    public int StreetId { get; private set; }
    [DataMember]
    public int NumberOfCars { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public IDictionary<string, string> HouseDetails { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public IDictionary<int, string> People { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public ISet<int> LampPosts { get; set; }

    public TestModel(int StreetId, string StreetName)
    {
        this.StreetName = StreetName;
        this.StreetId = StreetId;

        HouseDetails = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        People = new Dictionary<int, string>();
        LampPosts = new HashSet<int>();
    }

    public void AddHouse(string HouseNumber, string HouseName)
    {
        HouseDetails.Add(HouseNumber, HouseName);
    }

    public void AddPeople(int PersonNumber, string PersonName)
    {
        People.Add(PersonNumber, PersonName);
    }

    public void AddLampPost(int LampPostName)
    {
        LampPosts.Add(LampPostName);
    }
}
```

When I then try to serialize an object of this type using  DataContractJsonSerializer, I get the following error:

```
{"'System.Collections.Generic.HashSet`1[System.Int32]' is a collection type and cannot be serialized when assigned to an interface type that does not implement IEnumerable ('System.Collections.Generic.ISet`1[System.Int32]'.)"}
```

This msg does not sound right to me. `ISet<T>` does implement `IEnumerable<T>`( and also IEnumerable).
If in my TestModel class, I replace

```
public ISet<int> LampPosts { get; set; }
```

with

```
public ICollection<int> LampPosts { get; set; }...
```

then it all sails through.

I am new to JSON so any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: why do you need a `HashSet` or an `ISet`?

Comment: In the real application "LampPosts" would be a collection of reference types. LampPosts will not allow duplicates and will most likely be populated using NHibernate. I believe ISet is a good option under this scenario.

Comment: create a model wrapper that does this for you.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by model wrapper or how that would help in this scenario. The class above could be part of the domain model. It encapsulates both the data and behaviour. ORM tools ( like NHibernate) allow me to directly persist my domain object "state" to/from a database. I should not/do not need to add another level of indirection (like a wrapper).

Comment: Even if we do investigate the wrapper route, what I am trying to understand here is why the scenario in my original post does not work.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like this is a [known microsoft bug](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedbackdetail/view/797718/datacontractserializer-cannot-serialize-system-collections-generic-iset-t-even-if-it-derives-from-ienumerable).
List of supported interfaces is hardcoded in framework, and `ISet` is not one of them:

```
CollectionDataContract.CollectionDataContractCriticalHelper._knownInterfaces = new Type[]
{
  Globals.TypeOfIDictionaryGeneric,
  Globals.TypeOfIDictionary,
  Globals.TypeOfIListGeneric,
  Globals.TypeOfICollectionGeneric,
  Globals.TypeOfIList,
  Globals.TypeOfIEnumerableGeneric,
  Globals.TypeOfICollection,
  Globals.TypeOfIEnumerable
};
```

And yes, error message is incorrect.
So, `DataContractJsonSerializer` cannot serialize `ISet` interface, it should be either replaced with one of supported interfaces, or with concrete `ISet` implementation.