# DataContractJsonSerializer: collection type cannot be serialized when assigned to an interface

Tags: c#, json, serialization, datacontractserializer, datacontractjsonserializer

I am writing a WCF service that generates various XML and JSON formats for multiple clients. The code below generates a SerializationException:  'TPH_PriceListJsonItems' is a collection type and cannot be serialized when assigned to an interface type that does not implement IEnumerable ('TPH_IPriceListItems'). The XML part is working fine, but not JSON. I do not understand the error, my interface is implementing IEnumerable to represent a class wrapping a simple List<> so I can use the CollectionDataContract.

```
public class ReproduceDataContractIssue
{
    public static void Main(String[] args)
    {
        // Create test object - vacation products lowest prices grid
        TPH_IPriceList priceList = new TPH_PriceListJson();
        priceList.ListItems.Add(new TPH_PriceListJsonItem() { DestCityName = "Cancun", StayDuration =  7, LowestPrice = 1111 });
        priceList.ListItems.Add(new TPH_PriceListJsonItem() { DestCityName = "Jamaica", StayDuration = 14, LowestPrice = 2222 });

        // Serialize into XML string
        DataContractSerializer serializer = new DataContractSerializer(priceList.GetType());
        MemoryStream memStream = new MemoryStream();
        serializer.WriteObject(memStream, priceList);
        memStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
        string xmlOutput;
        using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(memStream))
            xmlOutput = streamReader.ReadToEnd();

        // Serialize into JSON string
        DataContractJsonSerializer jsonSerializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(priceList.GetType());
        jsonSerializer.WriteObject(memStream = new MemoryStream(), priceList);
        memStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
        string jsonOutput;
        using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(memStream))
            jsonOutput = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
    }
}

public interface TPH_IPriceList
{
    TPH_IPriceListItems ListItems { get; set; }
}
public interface TPH_IPriceListItems : IEnumerable<TPH_IPriceListItem>, IEnumerable, IList<TPH_IPriceListItem>
{
}
public interface TPH_IPriceListItem
{
    string DestCityName { get; set; }
    int    StayDuration { get; set; }
    int    LowestPrice  { get; set; }
}

[DataContract(Name = "PriceList")]
[KnownType(typeof(TPH_PriceListJsonItems))]
public class TPH_PriceListJson : TPH_IPriceList
{
    [DataMember]
    public TPH_IPriceListItems ListItems { get; set; }

    public TPH_PriceListJson()
    {
        ListItems = new TPH_PriceListJsonItems();
    }
}
[DataContract]
public class TPH_PriceListJsonItem : TPH_IPriceListItem
{
    [DataMember(Order = 1)]
    public string DestCityName { get; set; }
    [DataMember(Order = 2)]
    public int StayDuration { get; set; }
    [DataMember(Order = 3)]
    public int LowestPrice { get; set; }

    public TPH_PriceListJsonItem()
    {
    }
}
[CollectionDataContract(Name = "ListItems", ItemName = "ListItem")]
[KnownType(typeof(TPH_PriceListJsonItem))]
public class TPH_PriceListJsonItems : List<TPH_IPriceListItem>, TPH_IPriceListItems, IEnumerable<TPH_IPriceListItem>, IEnumerable
{
    public TPH_PriceListJsonItems(int capacity)
        : base(capacity)
    {
    }
    public TPH_PriceListJsonItems()
        : base()
    {
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The inconsistency arises from a difference in how JSON and XML represent collections.  For XML, the data contract serializers convert a collection to a nested set of elements -- an outer collection wrapper, and an inner element for each item in the collection.  For JSON, the serializers convert a collection to an array containing objects.  This seems reasonable, but there's a difference between the two: the XML outer element can have its own [XML attributes](http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_attributes.asp), but [JSON arrays](http://json.org/) *cannot have their own properties* -- there's simply no place for them in the standard.

This becomes an issue in dealing with [type hints](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb412170%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).  Type hints are properties added to the serialized data to indicate, in the event of serializing an interface or base class of a class hierarchy, what concrete class was actually serialized.  They are required to enable deserialization of the object without data loss.  In XML, they appear as an [`i:type`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms730167%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) attribute:

```
<PriceList xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Question32569055.V1">
    <ListItems i:type="ListItems">  <!-- Notice the type hint here. --> 
        <ListItem i:type="TPH_PriceListJsonItem">  <!-- Notice the type hint here also. --> 
            <DestCityName>Cancun</DestCityName>
            <StayDuration>7</StayDuration>
            <LowestPrice>1111</LowestPrice>
        </ListItem>
    </ListItems>
</PriceList>
```

As you can see from your own example, type hints can be added *for both collection and non-collection classes*.

In JSON objects, they appear as an added property named [`"__type"`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb412170%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
{
  "__type": "TPH_PriceListJsonItem:#Question32569055.V3",
  "DestCityName": "Cancun",
  "StayDuration": 7,
  "LowestPrice": 1111
}
```

But, as mentioned before, JSON arrays cannot have properties.  So, what does `DataContractJsonSerializer` do for polymorphic collection types?  Well, other than for a few standard collection interfaces which, as Fabian notes, are mapped to collection classes using hardcoded logic, it throws a cryptic exception to indicate that subsequent deserialization would be impossible.  (For comparison, Json.NET introduces an extra container object to hold collection type information.  See [TypeNameHandling setting](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SerializeTypeNameHandling.htm).)

The solution to this inconsistency is to serialize the collection explicitly as a concrete collection (`TPH_PriceListJsonItems` in your case) rather than as an interface:

```
[DataContract(Name = "PriceList")]
[KnownType(typeof(TPH_PriceListJsonItems))]
public class TPH_PriceListJson : TPH_IPriceList
{
    [IgnoreDataMember]
    public TPH_IPriceListItems ListItems
    {
        get
        {
            return ListItemList;
        }
        set
        {
            var list = value as TPH_PriceListJsonItems;
            if (list == null)
            {
                list = new TPH_PriceListJsonItems();
                if (value != null)
                    list.AddRange(value);
            }
            ListItemList = list;
        }
    }

    [DataMember(Name = "ListItems")]
    TPH_PriceListJsonItems ListItemList { get; set; }

    public TPH_PriceListJson()
    {
        ListItemList = new TPH_PriceListJsonItems();
    }
}
```

This eliminates the need for the type hint on the collection element while retaining it for collection members.  It generates the following XML:

```
<PriceList xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Question32569055.V3">
    <ListItems>  <!-- No type hint here any more. -->
        <ListItem i:type="TPH_PriceListJsonItem">  <!-- But the type hint is still here. -->
            <DestCityName>Cancun</DestCityName>
            <StayDuration>7</StayDuration>
            <LowestPrice>1111</LowestPrice>
        </ListItem>
    </ListItems>
</PriceList>
```

And produces the following JSON:

```
{
  "ListItems": [
    {
      "__type": "TPH_PriceListJsonItem:#Question32569055.V3",
      "DestCityName": "Cancun",
      "StayDuration": 7,
      "LowestPrice": 1111
    },
  ]
}
```

This design allows the class `TPH_IPriceListItems` to control exactly what type of collection is used internally rather than leaving it up to users of the class, and thus seems like a preferable design overall.

Comment: Great answer and its working fine. Also, I now better understand why __type was added in the JSON responses (and i:type in XML) after I switched from List<concrete class> to List<Interface>.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it is a similar problem to this [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6453988/isett-serialization-to-json-using-datacontractjsonserializer). The List of supported interfaces in DataContractJsonSerializer is hardcoded. So you can't add your own List Wrapper interface.

Why don't you just drop TPH_IPriceListItems like in the following code ? It is simpler and should also do what you want:

```
public interface TPH_IPriceList
{
    IList<TPH_IPriceListItem> ListItems { get; set; }
}

public interface TPH_IPriceListItem
{
    string DestCityName { get; set; }
    int StayDuration { get; set; }
    int LowestPrice { get; set; }
}

[DataContract(Name = "PriceList")]
[KnownType(typeof(TPH_PriceListJsonItems))]
public class TPH_PriceListJson : TPH_IPriceList
{
    [DataMember]
    public IList<TPH_IPriceListItem> ListItems { get; set; }

    public TPH_PriceListJson()
    {
        ListItems = new TPH_PriceListJsonItems();
    }
}
[DataContract]
public class TPH_PriceListJsonItem : TPH_IPriceListItem
{
    [DataMember(Order = 1)]
    public string DestCityName { get; set; }
    [DataMember(Order = 2)]
    public int StayDuration { get; set; }
    [DataMember(Order = 3)]
    public int LowestPrice { get; set; }
}

[CollectionDataContract(Name = "ListItems", ItemName = "ListItem")]
[KnownType(typeof(TPH_PriceListJsonItem))]
public class TPH_PriceListJsonItems : List<TPH_IPriceListItem>
{
}
```

Comment: A class wrapping the list allows CollectionDataContract to control naming of list elements. Without it, in the XML output, I get "<a:anyType i:type="TPH_PriceListJsonItem">" instead of "<ListItem>".

Comment: I misread the [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6453988/isett-serialization-to-json-using-datacontractjsonserializer) you mentioned, I believed it referred only to .NET interfaces. It is hard to imagine one cannot serialize implementions of simple interfaces.